# Finding lengths between characters in a string

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, scala, line

I have a function from a character and a string to an array of integers. The array has an index which is the a number within of times the character has shown up in the text, and the entry for this index is the distance from the preceding character that showed up in the text. If that character is newline, this function basically computes an array of the line lengths given the string.

```
val func: Char => (String => Array[Int]) = (ch: Char) => (str: String) => {
    var lens: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](20)
    var noCh: Int = 0
    var c: Int = 0 // accumlates till the next character is spotted
    for (i <- 0 until str.length) {
        c += 1
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
            if (noCh>= lens.length) {
                val newlen: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](2*noCh)
                Array.copy(lens,0,newlen,0,noCh)
                lens = newlen
            }
            lens(noCh) = c; c = 0; noCh+= 1
        }
    }
    lens
    }                                         //> func  : Char => (String => Array[Int]) = <function1>
    func('\n')("hello world \n hello wstsadfasdf \n sdlfkjasdf\n")
                                                  //> res2: Array[Int] = Array(13, 20, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                  //| 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Is there a faster method of solving this problem? Iterating through every character seems very slow, especially if you going through a very large string.

Comment: Please give a few examples: `f(x) === y` where `f` is the function about which you're asking, `x` is your input and `y` is the expected output. Let's say that I wanted a function that added 2 to a number, I'd write: `f(1) === 3`, `f(0) === 2`, etc.

Comment: An O(N) runtime is negligible for scanning a string and that could never be faster, unless you pre-scan the string one char at a time into a hashMap and you're only working with that same string over and over again. However, allocating arrays and consequently returning one with filled with zeros at the end is maybe a time waste, but is definitely a result blunder. Build a List[Int] or Seq[Int] and convert it an Array[Int] of the perfect result size, if you really must have an Array.

Comment: What's the result if ch is not the last character in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, a scan through the string is required. How else are you going to find the occurrences of `ch`? But you're definitely making heavy weather of it, as it's a one-liner:

```
def func(ch:Char)(str:String):Array[Int] =
 str.foldLeft(List(1)){(a,c)=>if(c!=ch) a.head+1::a.tail else 1::a}.tail.reverse.toArray

func('\n')("hello world \n hello wstsadfasdf \n sdlfkjasdf\n")
//> res0: Array[Int] = Array(13, 20, 12)
```

Or (even simpler, although probably a bit less efficient as it creates an array of strings)

```
def func2(ch:Char)(str:String):Array[Int] = str.split(ch).map(_.length+1)
```

Comment: Hmmm ok, thanks for the improvement in the code. The method of scanning the string though is still essentially the same which is what I wanted to improve on (but it seems that's only solution)

Comment: You can't do anything better than a linear scan though the string. It is pretty obvious you need to inspect each character to see if it is `ch`...

Answer (score 1):

How would that method work? By magically predicting where the next character is positioned? You could build a Map of sorted sets to speedup the query. Build-time would still be `O(n)` though. But querys can be executed in `O(1)`.